# Python not loading CSS

Tags: python, html, css, django

Ok I am new to Python, I am using Django here.

I cannot get my Python to see the CSS file and use it. I have tried hardcoding the path, server restarts, nothing works. I can get it to read a Bootstrap CDN however, I am not sure what is wrong.

My File structure is like so:

```
-migrations

-static
--music
---images
---style.css (the file that i'm trying to get)

-templates
--music
---index.html (where my link attribute is)
```

I am trying to load the static CSS file in index.html like so:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href= "{% static 'music/style.css' %}"/>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
body {
   background-color: red;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try with load static, make sure you static_root var is snipping to the static folder

Comment: @MauricioCortazar I am not sure what static_root is? but i tried {% load static %} and nothing happened.

Comment: read more about static https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

Comment: @MauricioCortazar ok I pointed the root at the static file, however nothing changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add following code in setting.py file

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"deploy_to_server")
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)
```

And use in your template

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href= "{% static 'music/style.css' %}"/>
```

Create static folder in your project

```
==> static ==> music ==> style.css
==> manage.py
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: This works, also I found that Chrome was caching the Style.css, so even after I got it "working" Chrome wasn't displaying it.